# How to update internal PHP

Tags: macos, apache, php

How do I update the internal PHP on OS X 10.7.1? I've loaded a current version but since I don't have a simple plan how to update it, I won't do it. I guess it's just easy replacing of files in `etc/apache2/`.

Would anyone please write me a quick manual?

Answer (score 2):

A quick method is to use [Marc Liyanage's PHP installer](http://php-osx.liip.ch/).

Open Terminal.app and run

`curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.6`